# Replace multiple lines using sed

Tags: sed

I thought I understood sed but I guess not. I have the following two files, in which I want to replace the "why" and "huh" lines with one different line. No whitespace at all.

> test.txt:

```
hi
why
huh
hi
why
huh
```

> test2.txt:

```
1
hi
why
huh
hi
why
huh
```

The following two commands give the following results:

```
sed "N; s/<why\/>\n<huh\/>/yo/g" test.txt > out.txt

out.txt:
hi
why
huh
hi
yo

sed "N; s/<why\/>\n<huh\/>/yo/g" test2.txt > out2.txt

out2.txt:
1
hi
yo
hi
why
huh
```

What am I not understanding about sed? Why don't both output files contain the following:

```
hi
yo
hi
yo
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your expression is almost correct, but it has two problems:

- If you want to match `why` as a word, you should put `\<` and `\>` around it. You did put just `<` and `\/>` around it. So, the first correction is:

  ```
  $ sed 'N; s/\<why\>\n\<huh\>/yo/g' test.txt
  ```
- But it will not work, either:

  ```
  $ sed 'N; s/\<why\>\n\<huh\>/yo/g' test.txt
  hi
  why
  huh
  hi
  yo
  ```

  Why does it replace only the second pair of lines? Well, in the first line, the `N` command will concatenate `why` to `hi`, leaving in the [pattern space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886564/what-actually-the-meaning-of-n-in-sed/5886784#5886784) the string `hi\nwhy`. This string is not matched by the `s///` command, so the line is just printed. Next time, you have the string `huh` in the pattern space and concatenate `hi` to it. Just in the next line you will have `why\nhuh` in the pattern space to be replaced.

  The solution is to concatenate the next line only when your current line is `why`, using the [address](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) `/^why$/`:

  ```
  $ sed '/^why$/ {N; s/\<why\>\n\<huh\>/yo/g}' test.txt
  hi
  yo
  hi
  yo
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted--to match several consecutive lines given that the first one is found.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it didn't replace both pairs of lines is explained beautifully in [brandizzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287976/brandizzi)'s answer.

However, if we take one step further. Say we have the following file and we want to replace "apple\njuice" with "pure\nmilk".

> test.txt

```
water water water water 
water water water apple
juice water water apple
juice water water water
```

The pattern filter way would not work.

```
sed '/apple/ {N; s/apple\njuice/pure\nmilk/g}' test.txt 

water water water water
water water water pure
milk water water apple
juice water water water
```

Because the 2nd apple from test.txt, which has been concatenated to the previous line by N, didn't get caught by pattern filter.

One solution I can think of is to use branch to concatenate all lines and then do the replacement.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/apple\njuice/pure\nmilk/g' test.txt 

water water water water
water water water pure
milk water water pure
milk water water water
```

It looks dumb, but I haven't think of a better way yet.

Comment: Second one would be better, because it won't have any surprise of missing replacements.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for `test.txt` file:

```
sed '/hi/! { N ; s/why\nhuh/yo/ }' test.txt
```

It means:

When not found `hi` in a line (it will be `why`), read next one and substitute all it with `yo`. Otherwise print directly (when `hi`).

Output:

```
hi
yo
hi
yo
```